# Solving $\int_0^1\int_{y}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{\sin x}{x} dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck at this question:

> $$
> \int_0^1\int_{y}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{\sin x}{x} dxdy 
> $$

It seems maybe I can use change of variable theorem to solve this but I don't know how... Can someone show me how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By re-ordering the integration, we can change the integral to the form

$$ \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^x \dfrac{\sin x}{x} dy dx $$

You will then reduce this to:

$$ \int_0^1 (\sin x - x\sin x) dx$$

Comment: o darn I didnt notice that at all! thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Change order of integration:

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{x^2}^x\frac{\sin x}{x}dydx=\int_0^1(1-x)\sin xdx=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you draw a picture of the region of integration, you can see that we have
$$
\int_0^1\int_y^{\sqrt{y}}\!\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dxdy = \int_0^1\int_{x^2}^x\!\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dydx,
$$
and the second integral should be easier for you to solve (the $x$ in the denominator will conveniently vanish).